# HTML buttons in Google Script not working

Tags: html, google-apps-script, social-media

My "Upload Content" Google Form linked to a Google Sheet's Google Script is working, but the HTML is failing. Google Sheet:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Timestamp | Upload Content | Email Address | Add comma separated tags | Shortened name |

Here is Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Website')
      .addItem('Search', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Search');
}
function search(emails, tags) {
  var returnData = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var esplit = null;
  if(emails)
    esplit = emails.split(', ');
  var tsplit = null;
  if(tags)
    tsplit = tags.split(', ');
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(tags)
      tsplit.forEach(
        (element) => arr.push(data[i][3].split(', ').includes(element))
      )
    if ( ( !emails || ( esplit.includes(data[i][2]) ) ) && ( !tags || ( arr.includes(true) ) ) ) {
      returnData.push(data[i]);
    }
    arr = [];
  }
  return returnData;
}
```

Here is Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="search();">
      <p><label for="emails">Enter people to view files from(comma seperated):</label> <input type="text" id="emails"></p>
      <p><label for="tags">Enter tags to find(comma seperated):</label> <input type="text" id="tags"></p>
      <button type="submit">find files</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="search-results"></ul>
    <script>
      function search() {
        var emails = document.getElementById("emails").value;
        var tags = document.getElementById("tags").value;
        document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML = null;
        google.script.host.search(emails, tags).forEach(callback);
      }
      function expand(id, thing, shortened) {
        if(id.innerHTML === shortened) {
          id.innerHTML = thing;
        } else {
          id.innerHTML = shortened;
        }
      }
      function callback(ls) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+ls[1]+"\">" + ls[4] + "</a>: Made at <time onclick='expand(this, \"time\", \"" + ls[0] + "\");'>time</time> by <email>" + ls[2] + "</email> with <tags onclick='expand(this, \"tags\", \"" + ls[3] + "\");'>tags</tags>";
        document.getElementById("search-results").appendChild(li);
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      time{
          cursor: pointer;
          color: blue;
          font-weight:bold;
      }
      tags{
          cursor:pointer;
          color:green;
          font-weight:bold;
      }
      email{
          color:white;
      }
      body{
        background-color:#FF8800;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried the HTML above, but the buttons didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you check the execution log for errors?

Comment: Hit inspect inside of the dialog when and if it launches then open up the console tab on the tools panel

Comment: I am @ahschools.us, so I can't inspect.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand rightly what you want to do. You want to get emails and tags from the user to write a list of these one in your google sheets file then use these one to make one folder by email ?

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do righly but if you want to connect your HTML to your JS in code.gs use the folowing code, it will pass in parameter "emails" and "tags" to search() in code.gs :

```
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(returnData){
     console.log("Ssuccesfully executed search");
     google.script.host.close();
   })
   .search(emails, tags);

console.log("Test of search : close");
```

I hope i replied to your question.